# Can I make my phone start recording sound without removing it from my pocket?

Tags: applications, buttons

Sometimes I would like to **record sound** from my Android phone, **very quickly**, without having to touch the screen.
*(Example: record funny situations in the street, funny sounds, etc. )*

**Can we launch sound recording "with hands in the pocket"?** (i.e. without using the screen)

More generally, is it possible to launch an app with hands in the pocket, by pressing one of the buttons during 3 or 4 seconds for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four years later I found a solution with [MacroDroid](http://www.macrodroid.com/)!

I start recording and stop recording by just pressing 4 times on the Power button (with hands still in my pocket!)

- Trigger: Power Button Toggle (4 times)
- Local variable: rec
- Action:

  ```
  If rec = False
       Record Microphone (Until Cancelled)
       Vibrate (short buzz)
       Set Variable rec = True
  Else
       Record Microphone (Cancel Recording)
       Vibrate (long buzz)
       Set Variable rec = False
  End If
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The only hardware buttons that can be used by apps (to launch other apps or start a recording) are the “camera” button on the device and the “media” button(s) on the headset. You’ll need a sound recording app that support it, or use an automation app like [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) with its [Media button](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/media_button.html) and [Audio record](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/audio_record_start.html) blocks.

Comment: Doesn't work on my Android 2 (I have 2.3.6). Another one that could associate 2-seconds-press of a button to some action?

Comment: It's more useful if you say exactly what you tried which didn't work.  Did you try (as ballzak suggested) a 'sound recording app which supports starting recording with either the camera button or the media buttons."  If you tried an app that does support that functionality but doesn't on your phone, did you then try his second suggestion, using Automate + blocks?  If so, what exactly didn't work.  Did you get Automate to do other things?  Could you get it to do actions with any of your device buttons?

Comment: You're right @ScoBe . I tried Automate app, but it seems to work only for Android 4+, it could not be installed on my Android 2.3.6. About `sound recording app which supports starting recording with either the camera button or the media buttons` I admit I haven't found something really relevant yet

Comment: @Basj Handling long-presses on hardware buttons are also off-limits to apps.

Comment: There surely *is* a solution, or a workaround... but how?

Comment: @Basj Try another automation app which has similar features, like Tasker or Automagic.